# change event on dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html form with lots of text fields and dropdowns. I need to iterate through all the dropdowns and then do some validations. In that page, only the first dropdown is visible, when the page loads. The remaining dropdowns are displayed based on clicking some radio buttons. I have written a jquery function to iterate through these dropdowns. But now it is iterating only through the first dropdown. Its not getting into the second one.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="input-container class_dd"> 
    <select class="class2" id="dd1" name="dd11">
         <option value="">Month</option>
         <option value="1">Jan</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-container class_dd"> 
    <select class="class2" id="dd2" name="dd22">
         <option value="">year</option>
         <option value="1900">1900</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Jquery**:

```
$('#form1 .class_dd').filter(":visible").each(function() {
    alert("1");   
        $(this).find('a:visible + select').change(function () {
             alert("2");
             //doing some validations
        });
});
```

Now only for the first dropdown, `alert(2)` is displayed. When I change the value of second dropdown, `alert(2)` is not getting triggered and so I am not able to validate that dropdown.
Can anybody help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the `<a>` that you reference in your jQuery selector?

Comment: Are you sure that you code is correct? I don't think that this code would trigger even the first dropdown

Comment: @oGeez..This dropdown is styled using selectmenu. So to get the value of the dropdown, i need to use like this find('a:visible + select')

Answer (score 0):

Register the change handlers for all teh select elements at once.... if the select is not visible it will not be fired

```
$('#form1 .class_dd select').change(function () {
    alert("2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(".class2").on("change",function(){

   console.log($(this).val()); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$('#form1 .class_dd select').on('change',function(){
   // code
});
```

`change()` was simply an short cut for `bind("change")`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code:**

```
$(".class2").on("change",function(){

     alert( $(this).attr('id') );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
$(this).find('a:visible + select')
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'a:visible + select', function () {
     alert("2");
     //doing some validations
});
```

Comment: Hi Jai..I am using $(this).find('a:visible + select') since the dropdown is styled using selectmenu..So my above code works fine for the first dropdonw. But when I change any value of the second dropdown, alert(2) is nt displayed..Tat alert(2) is displayed for the first dropdown.

Comment: Hi Jai..When I give on('change',function(){});, the alert is not working for the first dropdown itself...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
   <form id="myfrm">
    <div class="input-container class_dd"> 
        <select class="class2" id="dd1" name="dd11">
             <option value="">Month</option>
             <option value="1">Jan</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container class_dd"> 
        <select class="class2" id="dd2" name="dd22">
             <option value="">year</option>
             <option value="1900">1900</option>
        </select>
    </div>


$('#myfrm select').each(function(i,obj) {         
        $(this).change(function () {
             console.log(this);
             //doing some validations
        });
});
```

Comment: @Nish..Thanks for the reply..I am having trouble in my code, since we are using selectmenu for dropdowns. Because of the selectmenu, for getting the value of dropdown itself I have to use $('a:visible + select.class2').. When using selectmenu, the original slect element is rendered as hidden in the page. Instead we have <a> elements..Thats y i am using the above code in my question

Comment: I m just using the above code only..But when the page is rendered, in firebug I can see the <a> tags..So from firebug i wrote the above $('a:visible + select.class2') to get the dropdown value..I will get u the firebug code

Comment: <div class="class_dd">
<span class="inline-text-dob"></span>
<div>
<a aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="dd1_menu_456" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" role="button" id="dd1_button_456" class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all class2 ui-selectmenu-dropdown" tabindex="0" style="width: 88px;"><span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Year..</span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
<select name="dd11" id="dd1" class="dd-style class2" style="display: none;"
<option value="">Year</option>
<option value="1901">1901</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Hi Nish..after the <a> tag u can see a <select> element.that is the only code which is there in my html..but when rendered, it adds all the above code

Comment: $('#myfrm select:visible').each(function(i,obj) {         
        $(this).change(function () {})}) try this.It will give you only visible drop downs

Comment: Hi Nish..tried this..it works for the first dropdown..but again failed for the second one :(

Comment: This will work for visible drop downs only.Please tell what you want exactly.all drop downs/only visible ?

Comment: Hi Nish..I want to iterate through all the visible dropdowns. That is actually simple. But since the dropdown is using selectmenu, there is some complications..The above code with <a> tags and where the <select> tag is hidden is the actual code for the dropdown when the page is rendered. So could u please refer to that code with <a> tags and help me? I am not able to create a fiddle for this.or else i would have created a fiddle for ur better understanding